# Accessing Linked Resources in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, vxworks

I am currently working on an effort which makes use of Windriver's Workbench tool, which I understand is built on top of Eclipse.

Our source control tool is ClearCase and we are working primarily out of snapshot views located on the workstations of individual developers.  As a result the absolute path for each developer's view is different.  As deeply nested relative paths can be somewhat cumbersome (e.g. ../../../../../Some_Package/src/) we are using a Linked Resource `PROGRAM_ROOT_PATH` which identifies the particular view directory for a given developer.

This is working relatively well for for referencing header and library directories in the build properties, but we are trying to reference that Linked Resource from our build scripts in order to do build post processing such as copying the compiled program to a release area.

Accessing the Linked Resource as though it were an environmental variable appears to be the wrong thing to do as `$(SOURCE_ROOT_PATH)` provides an empty string.  Is there a way to access this information from Eclipse / Workbench from a makefile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look inside the .classpath and .project files in the root of your workspace project - I believe the linked resource should be defined in one or the other of those (probably .classpath). From your script (you don't mention if it is Ant, Maven, Gradle, etc.) you should be able to find a way to get that value out of the .classpath (through some plugin or custom code).

We use Eclipse, ClearCase, and Ant. The easiest way I have found to share projects is to include the .project, .classpath, and build.xml files in the top level of the project in ClearCase. Then when you create your view, mount it in your Eclipse workspace, and do a File -> Import, then choose Existing Project from the popup. Browse to the top-level of the project in the view and import it.

The paths in the build.xml and .classpath are relative from that point down, so it doesn't matter what the absolute path is up to the project. For example, your build will define your source directory as something like ./src/java, test directory as ./test/java, etc. Whether your absolute path is c:\workspace\project or /home/someuser/project or whatever doesn't matter to your build script.

Comment: Good point with respect to the script.  I clarified it in the question, as what I am trying to do is access this info from a makefile.  I'll look at those files.  Thanks.